# Delete polygons that have one or more side parts in common

Tags: python, geojson, shapely

I am trying to solve a particular case of comparison of polygons to others. I have **five** polygons distributed as in the figure below. The black polygon is the one with the largest area.

There may be other similar cases, **the main rule is to remove the smallest polygons among all those that have one or more side portions in common**.

The data for this case are in a GeoJson file as follows:

```py
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":1},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.4545135498046875,45.533288879467456],[3.4960556030273433,45.533288879467456],[3.4960556030273433,45.57055337226086],[3.4545135498046875,45.57055337226086],[3.4545135498046875,45.533288879467456]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":2},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.4545135498046875,45.52917023833511],[3.4960556030273433,45.52917023833511],[3.4960556030273433,45.53891018749409],[3.4545135498046875,45.53891018749409],[3.4545135498046875,45.52917023833511]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":3},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.4845542907714844,45.5298015824607],[3.5159683227539062,45.5298015824607],[3.5159683227539062,45.543388795387294],[3.4845542907714844,45.543388795387294],[3.4845542907714844,45.5298015824607]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":4},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.465328216552734,45.542667432984864],[3.4735679626464844,45.542667432984864],[3.4735679626464844,45.5478369923404],[3.465328216552734,45.5478369923404],[3.465328216552734,45.542667432984864]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":5},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.4545138850808144,45.56799974017372],[3.4588050842285156,45.56799974017372],[3.4588050842285156,45.57055290285386],[3.4545138850808144,45.57055290285386],[3.4545138850808144,45.56799974017372]]]}}]}
```

Is there a solution to delete **only** the two **blue** polygons(id 2 and 5)? In python.

By transforming the Polygons into LineString one could look if a Linestring is a portion of another Linestring ? But I don't see how to do it. Or maybe looking to see if the LineString of the black and blue polygons have more than two points in common ? But we can't convert a LineString into more than two points.

[image]

Comment: You can use a dictionary with one of x or y coordinates and intervals as values. Find intersecting intervals.

Comment: What do you mean by '**intervals** as values'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach may work for you using [`shared_paths`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shared-paths) which correctly calls out the path overlap between polygons 1, 2 and 5:

```
import json
import shapely as sh
import shapely.ops as ops
import shapely.geometry as geo

with open('./test.json') as f:
  features = json.load(f)['features']

for f1 in features:
  for f2 in features:
    id1 = f1['properties']['id']
    id2 = f2['properties']['id']
    if int(id1) > int(id2):
      s1 = geo.shape(f1['geometry'])
      s2 = geo.shape(f2['geometry'])
      coll = ops.shared_paths(s1.boundary, s2.boundary)
      if not coll.is_empty:
        print(f"{id1} and {id2} have shared path")
        # update your feature collection etc
```

I had to reduce the precision to 5 decimal places in your feature geometry for this to work as initially it only detects the overlap between polygon 1 and 2. The shared corner between polygon 1 and 5 is slightly out in your input FeatureCollection:

```js
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": 1
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [3.45451, 45.53328],
            [3.49605, 45.53328],
            [3.49605, 45.57055],
            [3.45451, 45.57055],
            [3.45451, 45.53328]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": 2
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [3.45451, 45.52917],
            [3.49605, 45.52917],
            [3.49605, 45.53891],
            [3.45451, 45.53891],
            [3.45451, 45.52917]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": 3
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [3.48455, 45.52980],
            [3.51596, 45.52980],
            [3.51596, 45.54338],
            [3.48455, 45.54338],
            [3.48455, 45.52980]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": 4
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [3.465328, 45.54266],
            [3.473567, 45.54266],
            [3.473567, 45.54783],
            [3.465328, 45.54783],
            [3.465328, 45.54266]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": 5
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [3.454513, 45.56799],
            [3.458805, 45.56799],
            [3.458805, 45.57055],
            [3.454513, 45.57055],
            [3.454513, 45.56799]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Robin ! I hadn't noticed the `shared_paths` method, it works well, very useful. Using geopandas the code is even shorter.